# How angularjs function can return html code with angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is problem

```
  helper.getDataForTriggeredUploadOfMFFile = function (isTriggeredUploadMF) {
            if (!isTriggeredUploadMF) {
                return 'None';
            } else {
                return '<spa ng-click=\"previewDataOnSmartAnalytics()>Preview Data</span>';
            }
        };
```

[image]

In browser there is not ng-click directive. How solve it?

Comment: Use `$compile` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to a typo in

> `return '<spa ng-click=\"previewDataOnSmartAnalytics()>Preview Data</span>';`

There is no ending `"`. Notice that you should be able to avoid the escape if you are using double apex inside singole apex.